# I have a tattoo, i wish to find the meaning

Tags: meaning, character-identification

[image: What is the meaning?]

What is the meaning of these letters, and is it somehow connected to eachother?

Comment: [武 / wǔ](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E6%AD%A6): martial, military (also used in [武术 / wǔ​shù](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E6%AD%A6%E6%9C%AF)) and [安 / ān](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E5%AE%89): calm, still, quiet, peace. But why [have a tattoo without knowing what it means](https://hanzismatter.blogspot.com/)?

Comment: I was trying to figure out if they have a meaning together, and if it was what the tattoo artist said it was

Comment: And what did he say it meant? (At least the characters look like the tattoo artist knew what they should look like, unlike many of the examples on HanziSmatter.)

Comment: He said it meant opposites of eachother to represent my bipolar psyche. Like a precursor to ying and yang or similar. Like the first one is chaotic violent turbulent and the second one is serene, calm, good, kind

Comment: Welcome to [Chinese.SE], a Q&A site about the Chinese language. We prefer to have the post to be as detailed as possible, and such info about the meaning by the tattoo artist is important to know for the context. You can always [edit] to add the details and improve your post. Lastly, consider taking a quick [tour] to get familiar with how this site works :)

Comment: *Like the first one is chaotic violent turbulent and the second one is serene, calm, good, kind* -- It is bullshit. "violent turbulent  vs. serene, calm"  is 亂與治；武 is a tool to create chaos ,  but 武 is also a tool to maintain order

Answer (score 4):

1. 武安 [Wu'an](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu%27an) is a city
2. [武安君](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AD%A6%E5%AE%89%E5%90%9B) was a title of a noble in Tang Dynasty -  [張守節](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BC%A0%E5%AE%88%E8%8A%82_(%E5%94%90%E6%9C%9D)): *舊注史記三大家之一 (one of the three great historians of old Chinese history*)

武安 means 以武安邦

以- with; use

武 - military; force

安 - maintain peace; keep safe; steady

邦 - nation

(steady the nation with military might or keep the nation safe with military power)